# Why is my Server 2012 R2 DISM failing to repair corruption

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, dism

Can anyone lend me some assistance in repairing my server 2012 R2 image?

I have a 2012 R2 VM, and have attached the install DVD we used from our datastore. I am then running the command:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:WIM:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
```

I can see the WIM exists in that location:

[image: Source WIM location]

The tool runs and stays at 20% for a while, then fails with an error that states:

```
Error: 0x800f081f, The source files could not be found
```

The DISM log states several error lines:

```
DISM package manager: The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature
```

The CBS log has loads of lines saying:

```
Failed to getfile from WIM sandbox process [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
Failed to look for the file WinSxS\wow64_some_package_name
Repr: not able to find replacement file for compenent
```

Followed by plenty of lines that say:

```
Repair failed: missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt
```

Can anyone tell me why it says the files cannot be found, when I am pointing at the same install.wim that was used to install Windows in the first place?

I even tried to extract the WIM to a location on the C:\ drive and use that, but failed with the same error.tel

Running /startcomponentcleanup results in error 14098, and DISM log says 0x80073712, which means CBS manifest is corrupt? Solution to which, laughably, is to run /restorehealth :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I tried a different repair source (Another 2012 R2 ISO I had, same version number I think but from a different download source).

I still got some component store corruption messages in the CBS log, but it seemed to fix enough to allow Windows Update to start working again.

Think I will do a restart and try an online repair using WU as the repairsource.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but have yet to find an answer to this.
Your ISO Server 2012 R2 will have more than just Std server 2012 r2 it might have a core install too and maybe datacentre install. You have to change indexes for the win command to work with your version.

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:c:\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```

on my 2012 R2 stand/datacenter media it has 4 indexes, to repair I need to make sure I use the right one
using the below command I can check the index name

```
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:c:\install.wim /index:1 
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:c:\install.wim /index:2
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:c:\install.wim /index:3
etc...

Index : 1
Name : Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERSTANDARDCORE
Index : 2
Name : Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERSTANDARD
Index : 3
Name : Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERDATACENTERCORE
Index : 4
Name : Windows Server 2012 R2 SERVERDATACENTER
```

so for my install I use

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:c:\install.wim:4 /LimitAccess
```

I use Index 4 since I installed a GUI version of Datacenter

Answer (score 0):

I ran the below command to verify my install type:

```
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:c:\install.wim /index:2
```

and then repaired with:

```
dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:c:\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```